# Shipping methods based on a defined date threshold in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, shipping-method

I want to enable the two shipping methods in WooCommerce like If the user order before the particular date then I want to enable the 1st shipping method and when the user order after the particular date then I want to enable the 2nd shipping method. Can anyone let me know if there is any plugin or code to do this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will enable a different shipping methods based on a defined date threshold.

You will have to defined in the function, your settings for:
- The shop timezone
- The 2 shipping methods rate IDs *(like 'flat_rate:12' format)*
- The date threshold

The code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'free_shipping_disable_flat_rate', 100, 2 );
function free_shipping_disable_flat_rate( $rates, $package ) {

    ## ----- YOUR SETTINGS HERE BELOW  ----- ##

    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London'); // <== Set the time zone (http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)

    $shippping_rates = ['flat_rate:12', 'flat_rate:14']; // <== Set your 2 shipping methods rate IDs
    $defined_date    = "2019-03-05";                     // <== Set your date threshold

    ## ------------------------------------- ##

    $now_timestamp  = strtotime("now"); // Current timestamp in seconds
    $date_timestamp = strtotime($defined_date); // Targeted timestamp threshold

    // 1. BEFORE the specified date (with 1st shipping method rate ID)
    if ( array_key_exists( $shippping_rates[0], $rates ) && $now_timestamp > $date_timestamp ) {
        unset($rates[$shippping_rates[0]]); // Remove first shipping method
    }
    // 2. AFTER the specified date included (with 2nd shipping method rate ID)
    elseif ( array_key_exists( $shippping_rates[1], $rates ) && $now_timestamp <= $date_timestamp ) {
        unset($rates[$shippping_rates[1]]); // Remove Second shipping method
    }

    return $rates;
}
```

Code goes on function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

> **To make it work, you should need to refresh the shipping cached data:** 
>   1) First, paste and save this code on your function.php file. 
>   2) In the Shipping settings, enter to a Shipping Zone, then disable a **Shipping Method** and "save" and re-enable it and "save". **You are done.**.

To get the correct shipping methods rate id, inspect their radio buttons code with your browsers tools (in cart or checkout pages), and use the **`value`** attribute data like:

```
<input type="radio" name="shipping_method[0]" data-index="0" id="shipping_method_0_flat_rate12" 
value="flat_rate:12" class="shipping_method" checked="checked">
```

> … so here it is **`flat_rate:12`** in `value="flat_rate:12"`

Comment: Thanks @Loic Can you please let me know How I can create these two shipping methods by the WordPress admin or programmatically
'flat_rate:12', 'flat_rate:14'

Comment: @R1222 You have to create your 2 shipping needed Methods first (setting the correct amounts in each)… Once done, inspect on cart page the shipping methods radio buttons to get the corresponding shipping rate IDs. The you will set this two shipping rate Ids in the function code…