# woocommerce shipping rate option on specific days and cut-off time

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have three shipping rates,

- Saturday Delivery - flat_rate:34 - £11.25
- Saturday Delivery - flat_rate:35 - £5 when order is =>£75
- Free Next Day Delivery - shipping_method_0_free_shipping19

Free Next Day Delivery is available all week.

I want flat_rate:34 to be visible on Thursday (all day) and Friday, and be available only until 12:30 on Friday, thereafter the "cut-off" the rate is hidden. If the total order amount is => £75.00 then flat_rate:35 is available and _rate:34 is hidden.

I want this option to be alongside the standard free next day delivery, currently if the order total is => 75 only the free_shipping option shows ... I want that AND the Saturday option (rate:35) to show.

How can I expand on the code below to the achieve the above?

Somewhere I am to include this

```
  ( WC()->cart->subtotal => $threshold )
```

,

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'hide_shipping_method_based_on_time', 10, 2 );
function hide_shipping_method_based_on_time( $rates, $package )
{

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
$threshold = 75;
$shipping_rate_id_1 = 'flat_rate:34';
$shipping_rate_id_2 = 'flat_rate:35';

// disabled on Mon/Tue/Wed/Sat/Sun 
if ( array_key_exists( $shipping_rate_id_1, $shipping_rate_id_2, $rates ) 
&& ( in_array(date('N'), [1,2,3,6,7]) ) ) {
    unset( $rates[$shipping_rate_id_1] );
    unset( $rates[$shipping_rate_id_2] );
}

// Cut off 12:30 on Friday's

if ( array_key_exists( $shipping_rate_id_1, $shipping_rate_id_2, $rates ) date('N') = 5 && date('H') => 12:30 ) {
    unset($rates[$shipping_rate_id_1]); // remove it
    unset($rates[$shipping_rate_id_2]); // remove it
}
return $rates; 
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Shipping methods based on a defined date threshold in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54898239/shipping-methods-based-on-a-defined-date-threshold-in-woocommerce)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'hide_shipping_method_based_on_time', 10, 2 );
function hide_shipping_method_based_on_time( $rates, $package )
{

    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
    $threshold = 75;
    $shipping_rate_id_1 = 'flat_rate:34';
    $shipping_rate_id_2 = 'flat_rate:35';
    $free_shipping_id = 'shipping_method_0_free_shipping19';
    $cart_total = WC()->cart->subtotal;

    // Disable on Mon/Tue/Wed/Sat/Sun
    if ( array_key_exists( $shipping_rate_id_1, $shipping_rate_id_2, $rates ) && ( in_array(date('N'), [1,2,3,6,7]) ) ) {
        unset( $rates[$shipping_rate_id_1] );
        unset( $rates[$shipping_rate_id_2] );
    }
    
    // Cut off 12:30 on Friday's
    if ( array_key_exists( $shipping_rate_id_1, $shipping_rate_id_2, $rates ) date('N') = 5 && date('H') => 12:30 ) {
        unset($rates[$shipping_rate_id_1]); // remove it
        unset($rates[$shipping_rate_id_2]); // remove it
    }
    
    // Show flat_rate:35 if cart total is >= £75
    if ( $cart_total >= $threshold && array_key_exists( $shipping_rate_id_2, $rates ) ) {
        unset( $rates[$shipping_rate_id_1] );
    }

    // Show both free_shipping and flat_rate:35 if cart total is >= £75
    if ( $cart_total >= $threshold && array_key_exists( $free_shipping_id, $rates ) ) {
        $rates[$shipping_rate_id_2]->cost = 0;
    }

    return $rates; 
}
```

Check this out

For change in it, let me know in a comment